# MethodInfo.Invoke autocast from Class to Interface not working

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo

I am trying to call a class method through reflection.

```
public class A
{
    public string B(IWork WorkToDo)
    {
        return WorkToDo.ToString();
    }
}
```

Class "Work" inherits from "IWork".

```
Type type = Type.GetType("A");

MethodInfo MI = type.GetMethod("B");

object X = MI.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type), new object[] { new Work() });
```

The above line throws argument error.."Expected IWork...instead of Work.."

If I write

```
object X = MI.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type), new object[] { (new Work() as IWork) });
```

it works.

I want to know why it is not able to infer and typecast automatically polymorphism or have I got it all wrong? Can we have a custom Binder class to do the plumbing?

Please help.

---

### EDIT

OK. Sorry guys for concealing the real problem. It works for above..also works with Array[] but throws error on List<>...

So my class would be:

```
public class A
{
    public string B(List<IWork> WorkToDo)
    {
        return WorkToDo.ToString();
    }
}

Type type = Type.GetType("A");

MethodInfo MI = type.GetMethod("B");
List<Work> WL = new List<Work>(); WL.Add(new Work());
object X = MI.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type), new object[] { WL });
```

Error is:

> Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Work]' cannot be
>   converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IWork]'.

Comment: What version of C#/.NET are you using? Or can you post more details? I cannot replicate the issue with C# 4.

Comment: :( i am using 4.0 only..

Comment: Can we see the definition of the Work class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your update, the problem becomes obvious. `List<Work>` *is not a* `List<IWork>`. `List<T>` is not covariant, as given

```
interface IWork { }
class Work : IWork { } 
class OtherWork : IWork { }
```

The method accepting `List<IWork>` could very well attempt to add `new OtherWork()`, and that would be a perfectly legal compile time thing to do. If the method was passed a `List<Work>`, adding OtherWork would be a completely illegal *runtime* thing to do, and thus the language prevents you from passing `List<Work>` where `List<IWork>` is expected.

What you might want to do is have the method accept `IEnumerable<IWork>`, which would allow you to pass your `List<Work>`. `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant (in C# 4), and it can be because it is readonly, there would be no writes or adds to the sequence.

Full working example:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class A
    {
        // note the change to the signature
        public string B(IEnumerable<IWork> workToDo)
        {
            return workToDo.ToString();
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            var type = Type.GetType("Foo.A");
            var info = type.GetMethod("B");
            var list = new List<Work>();
            var x = info.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type), new [] { list });
        }
    }

    public interface IWork { }
    public class Work : IWork { }
}
```

---

As for why it works for array, array variance is broken. It allows things at compile time that could be completely dangerous at runtime. The same issue could be present at runtime, if you have a method accepting `IWork[] array`, and you pass `Work[]`, the compiler will allow you to do it in this case. However, it would be perfectly legal (at compile time) to say `array[0] = new OtherWork();`, and you would get a runtime exception.

Comment: like my profile says "I am Small Time coder..mostly feeding on advice from generous experts from coding community".I HAVE BEEN WORKING ON THIS SINCE NOON WITH NO RESULT..your answer is spot on..thanks a lot..works now...thanks